# how to popup view using jquery or java script asp mvc2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want popup view in asp mvc; how to popup view using jquery? When I click on link I want to popup RequirementDetails view.

```
<p>
<%:Html.ActionLink(list.JobTitle,"RequirementDetails","Admin",new{id=list.RequirementID},null)%>
</p>
```

My jQuery popup view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.popup-link').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('<div><p class="popup-content"></p></div>').dialog({

            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            height: 300,
            width: 500,
            open: function () {
                $(this).find('.popup-content').load(href);
            },
            Exit: function () {
                $(this).dialog('Exit');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<p>             
<%:Html.ActionLink(list.JobTitle,"RequirementDetails","Admin",new{id=list.RequirementID}, new { @class = "popup-link" })%>
</p>
```

It is working (it opens popup box when I click the link) but the problem is when I click close popup dialog it is closed, and second time I click on link two popups open; how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sandy, please be more careful _which_ [edit] links you click on...

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `target` attribute of the anchor:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    list.JobTitle,
    "RequirementDetails",
    "Admin",
    new{ id = list.RequirementID },
    new { target = "_blank" }
) %>
```